# MS Access VBA Tab Control Q

Tags: ms-access, vba, tabcontrol

This is my first question here. I am a beginner so please bear with me.

I created a form for a survey in Access that has a tab control of 7 pages. Each page contains some questions. I added VBA code to make some questions be "enabled" based on the answers to previous questions (using the after update event).

Later on I decided to decrease the number of tabs to only 4 by increasing the number of questions in each tab by moving them there.

The problem is that the code is now not working after I moved the variables between tabs. For example, now some questions do not become automatically enabled when the answer to the questions preceeding them is "Yes" which was the case previously before moving the variables.

Any advices?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope you know that there are several simple to use survey applications on-line?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you without seeing the code or the control names, but double check every control name, and how they are referenced in the code. That should be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably move controls between tabs, not variables. If you moved controls using cut/paste, check do you still have event procedures on events (after_update, on_click, ...) for that controls?